# Indexing subtensors in TensorFlow

Tags: python, tensorflow

I want to get an output tensor by applying `index` to **subtensors** of an input tensor.

For example in NumPy,

```
import numpy as np

input = np.random.random((100,5)) # matrix
index = np.randint(5, size=(100,)) # vector
output = data[np.arange(index.shape[0]), index] # vector
```

gives me desired output (I want symbolic version of this).

Similiarly in Theano,

```
import theano.tensor as T
import theano

input = T.matrix() # symbolic matrix
index = T.ivector() # symbolic vector
output = input[T.arange(index.shape[0]), index] # symbolic vector
```

gives me a desired `output`.

How can I do this in **TensorFlow**?

```
import tensorflow as tf
input = tf.placeholder('float32', [None, 5])
index = tf.placeholder('int32', [None])
output = ???
```

Unlike the example with NumPy, the length of `index` (=1st dimension of `input`) is not fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the slicing with [`tf.gather_nd`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/array_ops/slicing_and_joining#gather_nd):

```
output = tf.gather_nd(input, tf.stack((tf.range(tf.shape(index)[0]), index), -1))
```

Comment: I'm afraid that gives me wrong result :< I expect the output to be a vector with length 100 (in the numpy example). But gather gives me a matrix. @jdehesa

Comment: What I want:
[ input[0][index[0]], input[1][index[1]], input[2][index[2]], ... ]
What tf.gather gives:
[ input[index[0]], input[index[1]], ... ]

Comment: @codebomb Okay, sorry, I misunderstood! I've edited it now.

Comment: Maybe no other way to do this simpler? Seems much complicated then what can be done with NumPy or Theano.

Comment: @codebomb Well, that's the only one I know (^_^U) You can check out how advanced slicing has been progressing in TensorFlow in [issue #206](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/206).